# Using community detection algorithm in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I am working on DBLP dataset( contains the metadata of over 1.8 million publications, written by over 1 million authors in several thousands of journals or conference proceedings series) which has following columns -

['id', 'title', 'authors', 'year', 'pub_venue', 'ref_id', 'ref_num', 'abstract']

I have to apply community detection algorithm on given dataset. My requirement is 
to get overlapping communities. 
For this I created a graph in igraph using above data, where id is a vertex value and ids in ref_id will be used to create edges. I tried different community detection algorithm available in igraph but not getting desired result-

I am using -

`community_multilevel()`

The resultant clusters I am getting from this algorithm is giving me only partition with best modularity. I want to understand how to get clusters at different level or dendogram ?

Edit : I used community_multilevel(return_levels= True) and for the above dataset ,which makes a sparse graph, my expectation was to get dense community at higher level but the no of community I am getting at each level is nearly same not much reduced. I need something similar to parition_at_level in networkx.

```
Total no of vertices  : 1632441
cl =  g.community_multilevel(return_levels=True)
print len(cl[0]) , len(cl[1]) , len(cl[2]) , len(cl[3])

output is : 1207787 1164960 1162115 1161959
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation of [`community_multilevel`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_multilevel) - it has a `return_levels` argument; setting it to `True` will return a list of disjoint community structures, one for each relevant resolution level identified by the algorithm.

Note that this won't be a true "overlapping" community structure, though, as each level identified by the algorithm will have disjoint communities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have  one more doubt, according to documentation return type is a list of VertexClustering objects, one corresponding to each level. How can I get which level corresponding to which Vertex Clustering object ?

Comment: If you use community_multilevel(return_levels=True) then it will return a list corresponding to levels.

Comment: @hsn  I tried to use this but no of communities is not reduced at each level. Is it like for sparse graph this algorithm is not of much help ? I have edited my query as well.

Comment: It may have happened that the algorithm failed to identify multiple relevant resolution levels so it just returned a single one. Maybe you should be using a true overlapping community detection algorithm (e.g., [CFinder](http://cfinder.org)). I have created a naive implementation of CFinder (probably too naive for the graph of your size) and hierarchical link clustering (yet another overlapping clustering method) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20082373/156771